# Results store in arraylist how can retrieve that arraylist added results in Android

Tags: android, arraylist

I am implementing synronous class in back ground process I am getting some results. These results are stored in array list in post execute method. How can I retrieve these results?

Code file

```
public class DownLoanPhoto extends AsyncTask 
    {
protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
        {  
                        ArrayList hhh=new ArrayList();
                hhh.add(PersonImage);
                hhh.add(layoutmsg);
                hhh.add(personName);
                hhh.add(msgImage);
                hhh.add(layoutPersonImage);

                Bundle bbb=new Bundle();
                bbb.putStringArrayList("val", hhh);
                onPostExecute(bbb);

            }
            return params;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
        {
//How to retrieve that array list results?
            layoutPersonImage.addView(msgImage);
            layoutPersonImage.addView(PersonImage); 
            layoutPersonImage.addView(personName);
            
            ll1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabmessage);
            ll1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            ll1.addView(layoutPersonImage);
            ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearlayoutMessage)).addView(ll1);
    
       } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of calling `onPostExecute` in `doInBackground` it will be automatically called.

```
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... url) {
        ArrayList<String> list=null;
        //Now manipulate your code get the right list 
        return list;
    }

    // -- called as soon as doInBackground method completes
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> list) {
        //Your ui code.
    }
```

Comment: hi my app purpose to display the views in one after another in custom linear layout in above functionality all list items displayed one time how to display one after another in adding views